# Predicate builder

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have a predicate builder that initially evaluates to `false`. Because of this, the very next expression should be a logical `Or`. But if I need a logical `And` I need to keep track of a boolean value. And this boolean value `hasPassedFirstCheck` is the thing I want to get rid of.

```
var cars = PredicateBuilder.False<Cars>();
var hasPassedFirstCheck = false;

if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.Truck))
{
    if (sf.ServiceTypes.Count < 2 && !hasPassedFirstCheck)
        cars = cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ);
    else
        cars = hasPassedFirstCheck
            ? cars.Or(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ)
            : cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ);

    hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
}

if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.SUV))
{
    if (condition && !hasPassedFirstCheck)
        cars = cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.SUV);
    else
        cars = hasPassedFirstCheck 
            ? cars.Or(x => x.CarType == CarType.SUV)
            : cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.SUV);

    hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
}

if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.Limo))
{
    if (condition && !hasPassedFirstCheck)
        cars = cars .And(x => x.CarType == CarType.Limo);
    else
        cars = hasPassedFirstCheck 
            ? cars.Or(x => x.CarType== CarType.Limo)
            : cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.Limo);

    hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
}
if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.Race))
{
    if (condition && !hasPassedFirstCheck)
        cars = cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.Race);
    else
        cars = hasPassedFirstCheck
            ? cars.Or(x => x.CarType == CarType.Race)
            : cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.Race);

    hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
}
```

This also isn't really OOP. Any suggestion to refactor this is really appreciated.

Comment: In your first condition, you use the same predicate twice. Is this intended?

Comment: Also is `condition` the same everywhere or is this simply a place holder for a check? If it's a random place holder then your question is off-topic because it is effectively pseudo code. It would be the best if the code to be reviewed would be compileable.

Comment: The `condition` was replaced with the real condition for the sake of simplicity and code that actually mattered. But I edited my post for those who think it's relevant.

Comment: This isn't Stack Overflow. You're on Code Review - *code always matters*.

Comment: Hm, sorry but I'm voting to close for now. I don't think the code you supplied works as intended and contains to much hypothetical stuff for us to do a sensible review.

Answer (score 1):

If your `condition` if false then none of your `if`'s executes. If it's true then `condition && !hasPassedFirstCheck` is always `false`, so your code simplifies to this:

```
var cars = PredicateBuilder.False<Cars>();

if (condition)
{
    // I guess you have a typo here as both expressions are same
    cars = sf.ServiceTypes.Count < 2 ? cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.Truk) 
                                     : cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.Truk);

    cars = cars.Or(x => x.CarType == CarType.SUV ||
                        x.CarType == CarType.Limo ||
                        x.CarType == CarType.Race);
}
```

And further reduced, but less readable:

```
var cars = !condition ? PredicateBuilder.False<Cars>() :
                        (sf.ServiceTypes.Count < 2 ? 
                                cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.Truk) : 
                                cars.And(x => x.CarType == CarType.Truk))
                            .Or(x => x.CarType == CarType.SUV ||
                                     x.CarType == CarType.Limo ||
                                     x.CarType == CarType.Race);
```

Comment: The `CarType` selected is not known upfront. I've updated my question with the real code of `condition`. Didn't think it was relevant, thus removed for simplicity, but added again.

Answer (score 1):

1. You seem to have a typo in your `CarType` enum, it should probably be `Truck`.
2. `cars` is initially `False` hence you can get rid of the `And` conditions because they will never evaluate to true anyway. So for example this makes this whole block useless:

   > ```
   > if (condition)
   > {
   >     cars = sf.ServiceTypes.Count < 2 
   >         ? cars .And(x => x.CarType== CarType.Truk) 
   >         : cars .And(x => x.CarType== CarType.Truk);
   >
   >      hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
   > }
   > ```

**Update**: Let's walk through the code a bit.

This is how it starts:

> ```
> var cars = PredicateBuilder.False<Cars>();
> var hasPassedFirstCheck = false;
>
> if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.Truck))
> {
>     if (sf.ServiceTypes.Count < 2 && !hasPassedFirstCheck)
>         cars = cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ);
>     else
>         cars = hasPassedFirstCheck
>             ? cars.Or(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ)
>             : cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ);
>
>     hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
> }
> ```

The initial predicate evaluates to `false` and `hasPassedFirstCheck` is `false` as well. Entering the first block this means `!hasPassedFirstCheck` is always `true` and can be omitted and `hasPassedFirstCheck` is always `false` hence the `Or` path is never taken. Given all of that the code boils down to:

```
if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.Truck))
{
    if (sf.ServiceTypes.Count < 2)
        cars = cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ);
    else
        cars = cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ);

    hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
}
```

Obviously the check `if (sf.ServiceTypes.Count < 2)` is redundant because you do the same thing in either case. So it can be further simplified to:

```
if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.Truck))
{
    cars = cars.And(x => x.CarType== CarType.DJ);

    hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
}
```

However the `cars` predicate is `false` at that point and `false && Something` evaluates to `false`. Hence the `And` condition has no effect on the result and the block can be simplified into:

```
if (filterObject.CarTypes.Contains(CarTypes.Truck))
{
    hasPassedFirstCheck = true;
}
```

Given all of this I'm not sure that

1. The code you supplied is actually the code you use.
2. That the code is actually doing what you expect it to do in the first place.

Comment: Yes the truk was a typo, but the 2 `And` was a result of resharper refactoring that piece of code. I have updated my question with the original code.

Comment: @Quoter: Resharper did the refactoring the correct way. Given your code that's what you can simplify it to.